# Closure and Co-Closure operations in the Pos category

Tags: category-theory

In Simmons' "Introduction to Category Theory" exercise 1.3.6 he talks about two monotone maps either way between 2 Posets:

```
S, T are posets
f: S -> T and g: T -> S are monotone maps
```

$F\dashv G$ is an adjunction

He goes on to say that g ∘ f is a closure operation on S and f ∘ g is a co-closure operation on T (actually he uses A ad B instead of S and T but I think that is just a typo since A and B aren't mentioned anywhere else)/

What does "closure" and "co-closure" mean in this context? The wikipedia articles on Closure (mathematics) and Closure Operation don't make sense to me in this context (although I see that they must talking about the same general concept)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, to show that $g\circ f$ is a *closure* you need to check three conditions:

- that $g\circ f$ *inflates*, i.e., that $s\leq(g\circ f)(s)$ for all $s\in S$ - this comes from part (a) of the exercise;
- that $g\circ f$ is *monotone*; and
- that $g\circ f$ is *idempotent*, i.e., that $(g\circ f)\circ(g\circ f)=g\circ f$.

If you now look at the [Wikipedia entry for a closure operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator) you should start to see how all the conditions match up if you think of $(g\circ f)\colon S\to S$ and the order $\leq$ rather than $\operatorname{cl}\colon\mathcal P(S)\to\mathcal P(S)$ and the order $\subseteq$.

So dually, to show that $f\circ g$ is a *co-closure* (sometimes called an *interior* operator) you need to check three conditions:

- that $f\circ g$ *deflates*, i.e., that $(f\circ g)(t)\leq t$ for all $t\in T$ - again, this comes from part (a);
- that $f\circ g$ is monotone; and
- that $f\circ g$ is idempotent, i.e., that $(f\circ g)\circ(f\circ g)=f\circ g$.